# How to read a txt file and check for certain text?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Hi so I am wondering how would I make it so my code will check the file for an id and this id is the id of a song and it is all random so I cant make it just for one id so basically this is the code someone gave me

code:

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile([PATH TO FILE], 'utf8', function (err,data) {
if (err) {
return console.log(err);
 }
 if(data.indexOf([TEXT TO FIND])){
 console.log("The text is in the file")
 }
 });
```

This code limits to finding a certain text from the file.
I want the code to check the song playing like for example on a youtube video where the code would compare the ending id on the youtube link to the video playing's id and if it is the same it will console log "The id is the same"...

The ending id of a youtube video is always 11 characters long...

Thank You for spending your time to look at this!

Comment: What do you mean by the "video playing's id"? Where is the video playing at? We need to know more about the whole application to help.

Comment: I am making a bot that is for a website that has a function where people can play youtube songs and I made it so that the bot will get the ending id of the youtube video and save it in a file now i need help trying to check if the video is in the file when someone says 'history' in the chat it will check the file and see if the video has the same id of the video playing! @TAGraves